# Is there a way to toggle the row selectable option on/off without recreating the tabulator

Tags: tabulator

title pretty much says it, I have users that have different roles they can choose from and I need to toggle the row selection functionality on/off depending on the role they choose, is this possible or do you have to recreate the tabulator to change this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not toggleable once the table has been instantiated, but you could use a [Selection Eligibility](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/select#setup-eligible) function to determine if the row should currently be selectable:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    selectableCheck:function(row){
        //row - row component
        return row.getData().age > 18; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
    },
});
```

You could tweak the above example to look at a global boolean that you toggle to determine if the table is selectable

Answer (score 0):

In this I can select rows with name `Oli Bob` only See [Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/select)

Use  as per your convinience

```
selectableCheck:function(row){
    //row - row component
    return row.getData().age > 18; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
},
```

```js
const tabledata = [{
    name: "Oli Bob",
    location: "United Kingdom",
    gender: "male",
    col: "red",
    dob: "14/04/1984"
  },
  {
    name: "Oli Bob",
    location: "United Kingdom",
    gender: "male",
    col: "red",
    dob: "14/04/1984"
  },
  {
    name: "Jamie Newhart",
    location: "India",
    gender: "male",
    col: "green",
    dob: "14/05/1985"
  }
];

let selectable = false;
const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tabledata,
  selectable: true,
  selectableCheck: function(row) {
    const name = row.getData().name;
    return name === "Oli Bob";
  },
  columns: [{
      title: "Row Num",
      formatter: "rownum"
    },
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      width: 200
    },
  ],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.4.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.4.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="example-table"></div>
```